# How to create a new column and add a random identifier to it with miller

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, csv, miller

I want to add a column with a randomly created "case number" to my `csv` file. The first 2 letters of the casenumber must be any letter from A-Z in capitals. followed by 5 random numbers.

input:

```
COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN
Test Ltd,John,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK2348020384
Test Ltd,Kate,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK4389223892
Test Ltd,Jake,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK3892898999
```

output

```
COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN,CASENUMBER
Test Ltd,John,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK2348020384,IN84903
Test Ltd,Kate,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK4389223892,TY93842
Test Ltd,Jake,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK3892898999,OL34307
```

How to do this with miller? I have the following command ready

```
mlr -I --csv put '${CASENUMBER}=xxx' then \
    reorder -f COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN,CASENUMBER input/input.csv
```

What to add to the above command exactly?

Comment: You may just be doing this for fun, but I would heartily recommend creating case numbers that are self-verifying, eg make the last digit derived from the rest of the id. See for example the [isbn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN).

Comment: Can the same case number be used multiple times or does each case number have to be unique? Do the case numbers REALLY need to be random or just unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not use Miller (mainly because I couldn't find a convenient way to do the random characters) but GNU Awk:

```
awk -i ord -v OFS=, '
    function randint(n) { return int(n*rand()) }
    BEGIN { srand(); A = ord("A"); Z = ord("Z") }
    NR == 1 { printf("%s,CASENUMBER\n", $0); next }
    { printf "%s,%c%c%.5d\n", $0, A + randint(Z-A+1), A + randint(Z-A+1), randint(100000) }' file.csv
```

This GNU Awk command pulls in the `ord()` function [from the `ord.awk` library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Translating-Between-Characters-and-Numbers) (which is distributed together with GNU Awk) to be able to convert between a character and its ASCII representation.  It then initializes the random number generator with `srand()` and precomputes the ASCII values for the letters `A` and `Z` for convenience.

If the current record is the *first* record (i.e., it's the CSV header), it outputs it with the string `,CASENUMBER` appended.

For all other records, it outputs the original record with an appended string after a comma.  The string is computed as two characters and a zero-filled number. The two characters are picked from the range `[A,Z]`, and the number is picked from the range `[0,100000)`.  The random picking of integers from a range is done using the `randint()` function, which I'm using unmodified [from the GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-rand_0028_0029-function).

An example output of running this on the given data:

```
COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN,CASENUMBER
Test Ltd,John,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK2348020384,HP88271
Test Ltd,Kate,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK4389223892,XS17910
Test Ltd,Jake,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK3892898999,UX00409
```

Note that as long as we're assuming that no field contains embedded newlines, we don't need to actually *parse* the input data.  With that assumption, it's enough to just append new data to the end of each line.

---

[terdon pointed out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767952/how-to-create-a-new-column-and-add-a-random-identifier-to-it-with-miller/767963#comment1465605_767963) that it may be a good idea to ensure that the computed case IDs are unique.  This does this by keeping track of the already generated IDs in an associative array called `seen`:

```bash
awk -i ord -v OFS=, '
    function randint(n) { return int(n*rand()) }
    function randid() { return sprintf("%c%c%.5d", A + randint(Z-A+1), A + randint(Z-A+1), randint(100000)) }

    BEGIN { srand(); A = ord("A"); Z = ord("Z") }
    NR == 1 { printf("%s,CASENUMBER\n", $0); next }
    {
        id = randid()
        while (seen[id]++ > 0) id = randid()
        printf "%s,%s\n", $0, id
    }' file.csv
```

I also moved the creation of the random case ID into its own function, as we need to call it twice from the main part of the code.

Comment: Nice! One nitpick: isn't there an (admittedly tiny) chance that one of the random strings will be repeated here? Would it be worth keeping track of them and discarding any doubles?

Comment: @terdon There was, strictly speaking, no requirement for uniqueness in the question, but I will give an alternative command in this answer to do that, as it's fairly simple to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice use of `ord()`. You might want to change `while (seen[id]++ > 0)` to `cnt=0; while ( (seen[id]++ > 0) && (++cnt < 100) )` or similar to avoid an infinite or unusably long loop if most combinations are used.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it in Miller.

```
alphabet="[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\", \"D\", \"E\", \"F\", \"G\", \"H\", \"I\", \"J\", \"K\", \"L\", \"M\", \"N\", \"O\", \"P\", \"Q\", \"R\", \"S\", \"T\", \"U\", \"V\", \"W\", \"X\", \"Y\", \"Z\"]"

mlr --csv put '$CASENUMBER=urandelement('"$alphabet"').urandelement('"$alphabet"').substr0(urand32(),0,5)' input.csv
```

You will have

| COMPANY | NAME | STREET | ZIP | CITY | IBAN | CASENUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test Ltd | John | Big Ben 343 | 4343 | London | UK2348020384 | BV134526 |
| Test Ltd | Kate | Big Ben 343 | 4343 | London | UK4389223892 | ZF321045 |
| Test Ltd | Jake | Big Ben 343 | 4343 | London | UK3892898999 | VQ302039 |

Comment: If you use single quotes around that long string, then you don't need to escape each double quote.

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda if I use only single quote and double string, I have mlr error: `mlr DSL: syntax error at "[" ...`

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas I brought it back, because with the syntax you proposed mlr gives me an error `mlr DSL: syntax error at "[" ...`

Comment: That can't make a difference, you'll find that with both syntaxes, `$alphabet` contains the exact same value which you can confirm with `typeset -p alphabet`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `urandint` to write a quick'n'dirty random character generator using string slicing:

```
mlr --csv put '
  begin{@chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";}
  func urandchars(n) { 
    x = "";
    while (n > 0) { 
      i = urandint(1,strlen(@chars));
      x = x . @chars[i:i];
      n = n - 1;
    }
    return x;
  } 
  ${CASENUMBER} = urandchars(2) . fmtnum(urandint(0,99999),"%05d")
' input.csv
COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN,CASENUMBER
Test Ltd,John,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK2348020384,MC47966
Test Ltd,Kate,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK4389223892,TM78575
Test Ltd,Jake,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK3892898999,WI58624
```

If you want to generate the character list externally, you could pass it in via the environment:

```
CHARS="$(printf '%c' {A..Z})" mlr --csv put '
  begin {@chars = ENV["CHARS"]} 
  func urandchars(n) { 
    x = "";
    while (n > 0) { 
      i = urandint(1,strlen(@chars));
      x = x . @chars[i:i];
      n = n - 1;
    }
    return x;
  } 
  ${CASENUMBER}=urandchars(2) . fmtnum(urandint(0,99999),"%05d")
' input.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= $. == 1 ? ",CASENUMBER" : sprintf ",%s%s%05d", ("A".."Z")[rand 26,rand 26], rand 1e5'
```

That assumes CSV fields don't contain newline characters. If they may, you could use perl's `Text::CSV` module to do proper CSV parsing and formatting like miller does.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ -s /dev/urandom ]] && seed="$(od -An -N4 -tu4 /dev/urandom)"

awk -v seed="$seed" '
    BEGIN {
        if (seed) srand(seed); else srand()
        FS = OFS = ","

        chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        numChars = length(chars)
        for ( i=1; i<=numChars; i++ ) {
            for ( j=1; j<=numChars; j++ ) {
                strs[++numStrs] = substr(chars,i,1) substr(chars,j,1)
            }
        }

        numDigitCols = 5
        numNumbers = length("0123456789") ^ numDigitCols
        maxUnqAttempts = 100
    }

    {
        for ( attempts=1; attempts<=maxUnqAttempts; attempts++ ) {
            id = sprintf( "%s%05g", strs[int(1+rand()*numStrs)], int(rand()*numNumbers) )
            if ( !seen[id]++ ) {
                break
            }
        }

        if ( attempts > maxUnqAttempts ) {
            printf "%s[%d]: Failed to generate a unique ID after %d attempts, reusing %s\n", FILENAME, NR, maxUnqAttempts, id | "cat>&2"
        }

        print $0, (NR>1 ? id : "CASENUMBER")
    }

' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh input.csv
COMPANY,NAME,STREET,ZIP,CITY,IBAN,CASENUMBER
Test Ltd,John,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK2348020384,TT93580
Test Ltd,Kate,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK4389223892,MP70836
Test Ltd,Jake,Big Ben 343,4343,London,UK3892898999,TM77788
```